# Redirecting to post detail page after editing a comment in Django causes 'NoReverseMatch' error. What am I doing wrong?

Tags: django

I want to do 2 redirects with url having 1 pk is that possible? please help i am getting error. I am working on a blog application. I have a views function for the user to edit his comment. my problem is this: when user clicks save button after editing, i can't redirect him to post detail page.

my views.py

```
@login_required
def comment_edit(request, pk):

    comment = Comment.objects.get(id=pk)
    form = CommentUpdateForm(instance=comment)

    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = CommentUpdateForm(request.POST, instance=comment)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            return redirect('blog-post-detail')
    context = {'form':form,}
    return render(request, 'comment_edit.html', context)

@login_required
def post_edit(request, pk):
    post = Post.objects.get(id=pk)
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = PostUpdateForm(request.POST, instance=post)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            return redirect('blog-post-detail', pk=post.id)
    else:
        form = PostUpdateForm(instance= post)    
    context = {
        'post': post,
        'form': form,
    }
    return render(request, 'post_edit.html', context)
```

my urls.py

```
from django.urls import path
from .import views



urlpatterns=[
    path('blogs/', views.blog, name="blog"),
    path('post_detail/<int:pk>/', views.post_detail, name="blog-post-detail"),
    path('post_edit/<int:pk>/', views.post_edit, name="blog-post-edit"),
    path('post_delete/<int:pk>/', views.post_delete, name="blog-post-delete"),
    path('comment_delete/<int:pk>/', views.comment_delete, name="blog-comment-delete"),
    path('comment_edit/<str:pk>/', views.comment_edit, name="blog-comment-edit"),
]
```

my html:

```
{% extends 'blog.html' %}
{% load crispy_forms_tags %}
{% block title %}Yorumu Düzenle{% endblock %}
{% block content %}
<div style="margin-top: 10%;" class="container">
    <div class="row mt-5 pt-3 fluid">
        <div class="col-md-8 offset-md-2">
            <div class="card">
               <div class="card-body">
                   <form method="POST">
                    {% csrf_token %}
                    {{ form|crispy }}
                    <input class="btn btn-primary btn-sm" type="submit" value="Kaydet">
                   </form>
               </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
{% endblock %}
```

the error i got:

## NoReverseMatch at /blog/comment_edit/42/

```
Reverse for 'blog-post-detail' with no arguments not found.
1 pattern(s) tried: ['blog/post_detail/(?P<pk>[0-9]+)/\\Z']

Request Method:POSTRequest
URL:http://127.0.0.1:8000/blog/comment_edit/42/Django Version:3.2.13
Exception Type:NoReverseMatchException Value:Reverse for 'blog-post-detail' with no arguments not found. 
1 pattern(s) tried: \['blog/post_detail/(?P\<pk\>\[0-9\]+)/\\\\Z'\]
Exception Location:C:\\python\\lib\\site-packages\\django\\urls\\resolvers.py, line 698, in \_reverse_with_prefixPython 
Executable:C:\\python\\python.exePython Version:3.7.8Python Path:\['c:\\\\Users\\\\USER\\\\Desktop\\\\neos_yapi', 'C:\\\\python\\\\python37.zip', 'C:\\\\python\\\\DLLs', 'C:\\\\python\\\\lib', 'C:\\\\python', 'C:\\\\python\\\\lib\\\\site-packages'\]
Server time:Fri, 26 May 2023 21:02:42 +0000
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/200P3.png)

Comment: The definition of the `blog-post-detail` url requires a pk.  But in `comment_edit()`, you're calling `return redirect('blog-post-detail')` without providing a pk...